# Obtain Column name(s) of database via PHP

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have a postgresql database and I am connecting to and reading from it via php. Ive put in php codes that give me back the result to the query i pass from my code.

Ex- My  code :(Note - My HTML page uses a form which asks for input and searches for the given input in the database)

```
<?php
        $result = pg_prepare($dbh, "Query1", 'SELECT * FROM test.bact WHERE disease = $1');

        $result = pg_execute($dbh, "Query1", array($disease));
        if (!$result) {
                die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
        }
        //$rows = pg_fetch_all($result)

/*// iterate over result set
// print each row*/
            while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo $row[0]." ".$row[1]. "<br />";
                }
```

From the above piece of code I get my information as strings separated by a space ( `echo $row[0]." ".$row[1]`)

```
example: Information at row[0]<space>Information at row[1]
```

What I want - I want the retrieved data in a more organised form i.e. with the column name.
How it should look like -

```
Name of Column : Data 
Name of column : Data ...and so on.
```

I know there is way in mysql using the `mysql_fetch_field`, but I wanted something for postgresql. Since I am new to php n databases I am not really sure as to how will I use this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `pg_fetch_assoc()` instead http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: You can then use `array_keys()` on a row, for a list of the column names

Comment: use `pg_fetch_assoc` + `array_keys`

Comment: The example shown in the link seems to be specifying the name of the column. Isnt there a dynamic way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [pg_field_name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-field-name.php) or [pg_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: could you give me an example. Ive tried the examples given in the php.net manual and cant get it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't - I used to work with PHP long time ago, and haven't any php tools or databases for now. Sorry.

What kind of problem do you have with examples?